# How can I check for the correct location of commas in a number entered by a user?

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

I'm looking for a good way to check a number that a user has entered for correct position of optional commas.

For example

```
1,000,000.00 = correct
1000000      = correct
1,00,000.00  = incorrect
,100,000     = incorrect
```

So it looks like I need to check to see that there is at least one number to the left and 3 numbers to the right of the comma, or is there a RegEx way to do this?

Comment: Who cares? Commas are to make it easier for the human reader to decipher how big a number is... not that politicians is Washington DC care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you going to use this for?  Or put another way, why care?  Why not just strip out all commas and convert it to a numeric type?

Comment: Yeah, that's my feeling as well... this sounds suspiciously like that annoying check used by banking websites to prevent you from entering a number without two decimal places. Though i suppose if you expected some traffic from international users, checking for "10,00" might be useful prior to stripping the commas...

Comment: I had about 1 hour to implement something in the existing validation and used something similar to the first answer above But I agree with your comment and now that I have a little bit more time to work with this is what I'm going to implement.

Answer (score 6):

```
/^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this website: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/commafy-numbers

Here's the code snippet:

```
String.prototype.commafy = function () {
    return this.replace(/(^|[^\w.])(\d{4,})/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
        return $1 + $2.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$&,");
    });
}

Number.prototype.commafy = function () {
    return String(this).commafy();
}
```

What you can do is replace all commas and then use this code to add in the commas yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Kind of a long way around for validating, but then again, why *not* go ahead and fix it?  You're only validating the formatting, not the content. +1 for thinking out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

[Here’s a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184) that answers your question. There are also many other number-related patterns there, including ones that are maintainable — something no one ever seems to worry about.