# Matching numbers with regular expressions — only digits and commas

Tags: .net, regex, numbers, matching

I can't figure out how to construct a regex for the example values:

```
123,456,789
-12,34
1234
-8
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Is "`-12,34`" considered valid? In everyday usage it is not and makes a HUGE difference on the resulting regex.

Comment: ',' == nutty European '.'

Comment: @user278618, if you edit your profile, you can change your name from `user278618` to anything you please.

Comment: @user278618 please see my updated answer. I’ve explained all the mysterious patterns I suggested, cited the source material where I got it all from, and then showed several **substantial** improvements, first with white space and comments, then with named groups, and finally with a fully grammatical patterns. Check it out!

Comment: Jason: not everyone uses `.` for separating integral and fractional part ...

Comment: `only digits and commas` ? That would be `[\d,]+`

Comment: @PeeHaa: could you explain what is you are still looking for, why the answers given so far do not suffice?

Comment: @FrankConijn he [wants](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17314212#17314212) to award [tchrist's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184)

Comment: Best reference for regex syntax I've found: http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt
*Note: Some features of the Onigurama will not be avaiable in Perl or other regex implementations, but the vast majority of definitions are applicable to most perl-like regex engines.*

Comment: @ThorSummoner What about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) :)?

Comment: @HamZa: Which he then is going to give himself to tchrist. I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @hamza nah, there's something compelling about a plain text document wrapped at 80 chars that makes it easier to understand. Or rather, the author of that text file was appropriately turse.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you only want to allow digits and commas, `^[-,0-9]+$` is your regex. If you also want to allow spaces, use `^[-,0-9 ]+$`.

However, if you want to allow proper numbers, better go with something like this:

```
^([-+] ?)?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$
```

or simply use [.net's number parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327135%28VS.71%29.aspx) (for the various NumberStyles, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28VS.71%29.aspx)):

```
try {
    double.Parse(yourString, NumberStyle.Number);
}
catch(FormatException ex) {
    /* Number is not in an accepted format */
}
```

Comment: Yep, see my addition - his question didn't mention if he wants to allow "only digits and commas" or if he wants to check for valid numbers.

Comment: that’s pretty nasty.  I don’t think it even answers his question. Then again, the question which @user278618 asked does not line up with the examples which @user278618 provided. I gave many solutions in my own answer, *none* of which have any of the many, many problems that yours has. It is possible that my `/^(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0123456789]{1,3}(?:,?[0123456789]{3})*))$/` will satisfy his needs, but it is impossible to tell because of the imprecise and conflictive wording. But certainly mine does a much better job than yours does!

Comment: I could just guess what exactly he wanted as his question was very unclear.

Answer (score 497):

## What’s a Number?

I have a simple question for *your* “simple” question: What precisely do you mean by “a number”?

- Is `−0` a number?
- How do you feel about `√−1`?
- Is `⅝` or `⅔` a number?
- Is `186,282.42±0.02` miles/second one number — or is it two or three of them?
- Is `6.02e23` a number?
- Is `3.141_592_653_589` a number? How about `π`, or `ℯ`? And `−2π⁻³ ͥ`?
- How many numbers in `0.083̄`?
- How many numbers in `128.0.0.1`?
- What number does `⚄` hold? How about `⚂⚃`?
- Does `10,5 mm` have one number in it — or does it have two?
- Is `∛8³` a number — or is it three of them?
- What number does `ↀↀⅮⅭⅭⅬⅫ AUC` represent, 2762 or 2009?
- Are `४५६७` and `৭৮৯৮` numbers?
- What about `0377`, `0xDEADBEEF`, and `0b111101101`?
- Is `Inf` a number?  Is `NaN`?
- Is `④②` a number? What about `⓰`?
- How do you feel about `㊅`?
- What do `ℵ₀` and `ℵ₁` have to do with numbers? Or `ℝ`, `ℚ`, and `ℂ`?

### Suggested Patterns

Also, are you familiar with these patterns?  Can you explain the pros and cons of each?

1. `/\D/`
2. `/^\d+$/`
3. `/^\p{Nd}+$/`
4. `/^\pN+$/`
5. `/^\p{Numeric_Value:10}$/`
6. `/^\P{Numeric_Value:NaN}+$/`
7. `/^-?\d+$/`
8. `/^[+-]?\d+$/`
9. `/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/`
10. `/^-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$/`
11. `/^([+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?$/`
12. `/^((\d)(?(?=(\d))|$)(?(?{ord$3==1+ord$2})(?1)|$))$/`
13. `/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))$/`
14. `/^(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}):(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}):(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}):(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}):(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}):(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}))$/`
15. `/^(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0123456789]+))$/`
16. `/(([+-]?)([0123456789]{1,3}(?:,?[0123456789]{3})*))/`
17. `/^(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0123456789]{1,3}(?:,?[0123456789]{3})*))$/`
18. `/^(?:(?i)(?:[+-]?)(?:(?=[0123456789]|[.])(?:[0123456789]*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[0123456789]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[E])(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0123456789]+))|))$/`
19. `/^(?:(?i)(?:[+-]?)(?:(?=[01]|[.])(?:[01]{1,3}(?:(?:[,])[01]{3})*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[01]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[E])(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[01]+))|))$/`
20. `/^(?:(?i)(?:[+-]?)(?:(?=[0123456789ABCDEF]|[.])(?:[0123456789ABCDEF]{1,3}(?:(?:[,])[0123456789ABCDEF]{3})*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[0123456789ABCDEF]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[G])(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0123456789ABCDEF]+))|))$/`
21. `/((?i)([+-]?)((?=[0123456789]|[.])([0123456789]{1,3}(?:(?:[_,]?)[0123456789]{3})*)(?:([.])([0123456789]{0,}))?)(?:([E])(([+-]?)([0123456789]+))|))/`

I suspect that some of those patterns above *may* serve your needs.  But I cannot tell you which one or ones — or, if none, supply you another — because you haven’t said what you mean by “number”.

As you see, there are **a huge number** of number possibilities: quite probably ℵ₁ worth of them, in fact.  ☺

### Key to Suggested Patterns

Each numbered explanation listed below describes the pattern of the corresponding numbered pattern listed above.

1. Match if there are any *non-digits* anywhere in the string, including whitespace like line breaks.
2. Match only if the string contains nothing but digits, with the possible exception of a trailing line break.  Note that a digit is defined as having the property General Category Decimal Number, which is available as `\p{Nd}`, `\p{Decimal_Number}`, or `\p{General_Category=Decimal_Number}`.  This is turn is actually just a reflection of those code points whose Numeric Type category is Decimal, which is available as `\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal}`.
3. This is the same as 2 in most regex languages.  Java is an exception here, because it does not map the simple charclass escapes like `\w` and `\W`, `\d` and `\D`, `\s` and `\S`, and `\b` or `\B`  into the appropriate Unicode property. That means you must not use any of those eight one-character escapes for any Unicode data in Java, because they work only on ASCII even though Java always uses Unicode characters internally.
4. This is slightly different from 3 in that it isn’t limited to decimal numbers, but can be any number at all; that is,
   any character with the `\pN`, `\p{Number}`, or `\p{General_Category=Number}` property.  These include `\p{Nl}` or `\p{Letter_Number}` for things like Roman numerals and `\p{No}` or `\p{Other_Number}`  for subscripted and subscripted numbers, fractions, and circled numbers — amongst others, like counting rods.
5. This matches only those strings composed entirely of numbers whose decimal value is 10, so things like `Ⅹ` the Roman numeral ten, and `⑩`, `⑽`, `⒑`, `⓾`, `❿`, `➉`, and `➓`.
6. Only those strings that contain characters that lack the Numeric Value NaN; in other words, all chars must have some numeric value.
7. Matches only Decimal Numbers, optionally with a leading HYPHEN MINUS.
8. Same as 7 but now also works if the sign is plus instead of minus.
9. Looks for decimal numbers, with optional HYPHEN MINUS and optional FULL STOP plus zero or more decimal numbers following.
10. Same as 9 but doesn't require digits before the dot if it has some afterwards.
11. Standard floating-point notation per C and many other languages, allowing for scientific notation.
12. Finds numbers composed only of two or more decimals of any script in descending order, like 987 or 54321.  This recursive regex includes a callout to Perl code that checks whether the look ahead digit has a code point value that is the successor of the current digit; that is, its ordinal value is one greater. One could do this in PCRE using a C function as the callout.
13. This looks for a valid IPv4 address with four decimal numbers in the valid range, like 128.0.0.1 or 255.255.255.240, but not 999.999.999.999.
14. This looks for a valid MAC addr, so six colon-separate pairs of two ASCII hex digits.
15. This looks for whole numbers in the ASCII range with an optional leading sign.  This is the normal pattern for matching ASCII integers.
16. This is like 15, except that it requires a comma to separate groups of three.
17. This is like 15, except that the comma for separating groups is now optional.
18. This is the normal pattern for matching C-style floating-point numbers in ASCII.
19. This is like 18, but requiring a comma to separate groups of 3 and in base-2 instead of in base-10.
20. This is like 19, but in hex.  Note that the optional exponent is now indicated by a G instead of an E, since E is a valid hex digit.
21. This checks that the string contains a C-style floating-point number, but with an optional grouping separator every three digits of either a comma or an underscore (LOW LINE) between them.  It also stores that string into the `\1` capture group, making available as `$1` after the match succeeds.

### Sources and Maintainability

Patterns number 1,2,7–11 come from a previous incarnation of the Perl *Frequently Asked Questions* list in the question, “How do I validate input?”.  That section has been replaced by a suggestion to use the [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common) module, written by [Abigail](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/) and [Damian Conway](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/).  The original patterns can still be found in Recipe 2.1 of the [*Perl Cookbook*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135), “Checking Whether a String Is a Valid Number”, solutions to which can be found for a dizzying number of diverse languages, including ada, common lisp, groovy, guile, haskell, java, merd, ocaml, php, pike, python, rexx, ruby, and tcl at the [the PLEAC project](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/).

Pattern 12 could be more legibly rewritten

```
m{
    ^
    (
        ( \d )
        (?(?= ( \d ) ) | $ )
        (?(?{ ord $3 == 1 + ord $2 }) (?1) | $ )
    )
    $
}x
```

It uses [regex recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031112/regular-expression-matching/4034386#4034386), which is found in many pattern engines, including Perl and all the PCRE-derived languages.  But it also uses an embedded code callout as the test of its second conditional pattern; to my knowledge, code callouts are available only in Perl and PCRE.

Patterns 13–21 were derived from the aforementioned Regexp::Common module. Note that for brevity, these are all written without the whitespace and comments that you would definitely want in production code.  Here is how that might look in `/x` mode:

```
$real_rx = qr{ (   # start $1 to hold entire pattern
    ( [+-]? )                  # optional leading sign, captured into $2
    (                          # start $3
        (?=                    # look ahead for what next char *will* be
            [0123456789]       #    EITHER:  an ASCII digit
          | [.]                #    OR ELSE: a dot
        )                      # end look ahead
        (                      # start $4
           [0123456789]{1,3}       # 1-3 ASCII digits to start the number
           (?:                     # then optionally followed by
               (?: [_,]? )         # an optional grouping separator of comma or underscore
               [0123456789]{3}     # followed by exactly three ASCII digits
           ) *                     # repeated any number of times
        )                          # end $4
        (?:                        # begin optional cluster
             ( [.] )               # required literal dot in $5
             ( [0123456789]{0,} )  # then optional ASCII digits in $6
        ) ?                        # end optional cluster
     )                         # end $3
    (?:                        # begin cluster group
        ( [E] )                #   base-10 exponent into $7
        (                      #   exponent number into $8
            ( [+-] ? )         #     optional sign for exponent into $9
            ( [0123456789] + ) #     one or more ASCII digits into $10
        )                      #   end $8
      |                        #   or else nothing at all
    )                          # end cluster group
) }xi;          # end $1 and whole pattern, enabling /x and /i modes
```

From a software engineering perspective, there are still several issues with the style used in the `/x` mode version immediately above.  First, there is a great deal of code repetition, where you see the same `[0123456789]`; what happens if one of those sequences accidentally leaves a digit out?  Second, you are relying on positional parameters, which you must count.  That means you might write something like:

```
(
  $real_number,          # $1
  $real_number_sign,     # $2
  $pre_exponent_part,    # $3
  $pre_decimal_point,    # $4
  $decimal_point,        # $5
  $post_decimal_point,   # $6
  $exponent_indicator,   # $7
  $exponent_number,      # $8
  $exponent_sign,        # $9
  $exponent_digits,      # $10
) = ($string =~ /$real_rx/);
```

which is frankly abominable!  It is easy to get the numbering wrong, hard to remember what symbolic names go where, and tedious to write, especially if you don’t need all those pieces.  Rewriting that to used named groups instead of just numbered ones. Again, I’ll use Perl syntax for the variables, but the contents of the Pattern should work anywhere that named groups are supported.

```
use 5.010;              # Perl got named patterns in 5.10
$real_rx = qr{
  (?<real_number>
    # optional leading sign
    (?<real_number_sign> [+-]? )
    (?<pre_exponent_part>
        (?=                         # look ahead for what next char *will* be
            [0123456789]            #    EITHER:  an ASCII digit
          | [.]                     #    OR ELSE: a dot
        )                           # end look ahead
        (?<pre_decimal_point>
            [0123456789]{1,3}       # 1-3 ASCII digits to start the number
            (?:                     # then optionally followed by
                (?: [_,]? )         # an optional grouping separator of comma or underscore
                [0123456789]{3}     # followed by exactly three ASCII digits
            ) *                     # repeated any number of times
         )                          # end <pre_decimal_part>
         (?:                        # begin optional anon cluster
            (?<decimal_point> [.] ) # required literal dot
            (?<post_decimal_point>
                [0123456789]{0,}  )
         ) ?                        # end optional anon cluster
   )                                # end <pre_exponent_part>
   # begin anon cluster group:
   (?:
       (?<exponent_indicator> [E] ) #   base-10 exponent
       (?<exponent_number>          #   exponent number
           (?<exponent_sign>   [+-] ?         )
           (?<exponent_digits> [0123456789] + )
       )                      #   end <exponent_number>
     |                        #   or else nothing at all
   )                          # end anon cluster group
 )                            # end <real_number>
}xi;
```

Now the abstractions are named, which helps.  You can pull the groups out by name, and you only need the ones you care about.  For example:

```
if ($string =~ /$real_rx/) {
    ($pre_exponent, $exponent_number) =
        @+{ qw< pre_exponent exponent_number > };
}
```

There’s one more thing to do this pattern to make it still more maintainable. The problem is that there’s still too much repetition, which means it’s too easily changed in one place but not in another.  If you were doing a McCabe analysis, you would say its complexity metric is too high.  Most of us would just say it’s too indented.  This makes it hard to follow.  To fix all these things, what we need is a “grammatical pattern”, one with a definition block to create named abstractions, which we then treat somewhat like a subroutine call later on in the match.

```
use 5.010;              # Perl first got regex subs in v5.10
$real__rx = qr{ 

    ^                   # anchor to front
    (?&real_number)     # call &real_number regex sub
    $                   # either at end or before final newline

  ##################################################
  # the rest is definition only; think of         ##
  # each named buffer as declaring a subroutine   ##
  # by that name                                  ##
  ##################################################
  (?(DEFINE)
      (?<real_number>
          (?&mantissa)
          (?&abscissa) ?

      )
      (?<abscissa>
          (?&exponent_indicator)
          (?&exponent)
      )
      (?<exponent>
          (&?sign)    ?
          (?&a_digit) +
      )
      (?<mantissa>
         # expecting either of these....
         (?= (?&a_digit)
           | (?&point)
         )
         (?&a_digit) {1,3}
         (?: (?&digit_separator) ?
             (?&a_digit) {3}
         ) *
         (?: (?&point)
             (?&a_digit) *
         ) ?
      )
      (?<point>               [.]     )
      (?<sign>                [+-]    )
      (?<digit_separator>     [_,]    )
      (?<exponent_indicator>  [Ee]    )
      (?<a_digit>             [0-9]   )
   ) # end DEFINE block
}x;
```

See how **insanely better** the grammatical pattern is than the original line-noisy pattern?  It’s also far easier to get the syntax right: I typed that in without even one regex syntax error that needed correcting. (OK fine, I typed all the others in without any syntax errors either, but I've been doing this for a while. :)

Grammatical patterns look much more like a BNF than the ugly old regular expressions that people have come to hate.  They are far easier to read, write, and maintain. So let’s have no more ugly patterns, OK?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I hope that now with the elaborate explanation answering my original, *quite non-rhetorical* question, that you don’t just smile but indeed grin from ear to ear! :)

Comment: Very nice answer.  However, the question was about [tag:.net] and not PCRE.  So I'm sure a lot of the specific examples won't work (or the implementation details change)...  but it's still awesome...

Comment: Love this answer, it makes you think harder! However, dealing with non-ascii decimal digit characters in .NET seems quite tricky - any idea how to make int.Parse accept a string like "໘"?

Comment: @ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ: No idea how to do it using Microsoft, but it’s totally trivial with the latest Perl release: `perl -Mv5.14 -MUnicode::UCD=num -CSA -E 'say "$_ is ",num($_) for @ARGV' "४५६७" "໓໑໔໑໕໙"` prints out `४५६७ is 4567 ໓໑໔໑໕໙ is 314159`. That means all you need to do for digit strings is grab them with `/(\d+)/` and call the [Unicode::UCD::num](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/lib/Unicode/UCD.pm#num) function on it. I don’t know how good Microsoft’s international support is, but it has to be better than Java’s.

Comment: Minor con to the numeric patterns: they all use `$` where `\z` is probably better. :)

Comment: Great answer - but you have 21 patterns and 20 explanations. :)

Comment: I have an excellent idea, let's have a debate whether there are ℵ₁ meaningful number regexps or only ℵ₀ of them.

Comment: @AnthonyMills Yeah, I think he skipped #12. I think. :-)

Comment: "I don’t know how good Microsoft’s international support is, but it has to be better than Java’s" - ha! I don't think there is anything that will parse/convert "native numbers" in .NET (unless you do it manually). The digit substitution only happens at the display level.

Comment: @chx There may be more than ℵ₁. Since the cardinality of a powerset is always greater than the original, we could always define new "numbers" from the power set generated by our previous set. Note however you'll have to take in the generalized continuum hypothesis to go from aleph_i to aleph_i+1. What bothers me about this argument is the fact that the set of all reg-ex programs is only _countable_; we would have to have some kind of meta- "set of reg-ex's" to go up this ladder.

Comment: I think you're blowing it out of proportion. The question was about constructing regex for numbers involving digits and commas only.

Comment: To see the universe in a grain of sand - regex, readability, framing the question, robustness, clarity, illumination - eternity in an hour - how much wisdom is compressed into this answer?

Comment: @AnthonyMills The missing answer was there, but it ran into another because it lacked a list numbering. Fixed now. Thx.

Comment: I don't see any reference to "number" in the original question. Maybe somebody changed the question, but despite the length of your response, I don't think you actually answered the question. And this is a technical site, being all philosophical by answering a question with another question is very Socrates, but often not very useful.

Comment: OP, you have got a head shot :)

Comment: @stu: Do you mean that answering by the regex `123,456,789|-12,34|1234|-8` would have been better?

Comment: actually, that's a good idea. Wish I had thought of it. :-) My point was that while the response was informative it wasn't really an answer to the question. Maybe the question was a bit sloppy, but if you were to ask me "how many legs does a dog have" and my response was to give you an encyclopedia, that wouldn't be quite what you were looking for.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Advanced Regex-Fu > Common validation > Numeric", about 2/3 down.

Comment: @aliteralmind Thanks very much. I see at least one oversight in that posting (in an unrelated section). I suppose I can always edit it myself, assuming that would step on noöne’s toes.

Comment: @tchrist: Actually, HamZa added it in the original version. As far as the oversight, feel free to take care of it yourself, or you can tell me what you mean. He just started this yesterday morning, and I've been spending a good amount of time on it. Great stuff.

Comment: Only an tchrist could be _this_ thorough.

Comment: Another shining example of a 1-line problem being given an 87-line solution.

Comment: Funny, the word "number" does not appear anywhere in the posted question.

Comment: Wow, I haven't yet seen a question, but your answer impresses! +1 man!

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$
```

Allows for:

```
1
12
.99
12.34 
-18.34
12,345.67
999,999,999,999,999.99
```

Answer (score 7):

Since this question has been reopened four years later, I'd like to offer a different take. As someone spends a lot of time working with regex, my view is this:

**A. If Possible, Don't Use Regex To Validate Numbers**

If at all possible, use your language. There may be functions to help you determine if the value contained by a string is a valid number. That being said, if you're accepting a variety of formats (commas, etc.) you may not have a choice.

**B. Don't Write the Regex Manually to Validate a Number Range**

- Writing a regex to match a number in a given range is hard. You can make a mistake even writing a regex to [match a number between 1 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24325950/1078583).
- Once you have a regex for a number range, it's hard to debug. First, it's awful to look at. Second, how can you be sure it **matches all the values you want without matching any of the values you don't want?** Frankly, if you're by yourself, without peers looking over your shoulder, you can't. The best debugging technique is to output a whole range of numbers programmatically and check them against the regex.
- Fortunately, there are tools to generate a regex for a number range automatically.

**C. Spend your Regex Energy Wisely: Use Tools**

- Matching numbers in a given range is a problem that has been solved. There's no need for you to try to reinvent the wheel. It's a problem that can be solved mechanically, by a program, in a way that is guaranteed to be error-free. Take advantage of that free ride.
- Solving a number-range regex may be interesting for learning purposes a couple of times. Beyond that, if you have energy to invest in furthering your regex skills, spend it on something useful, such as deepening your understanding of [regex greed](http://rexegg.com/regex-greed.html), reading up on [Unicode regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), playing with zero-width matches or recursion, reading the [SO regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) and discovering neat tricks such as how to [exclude certain patterns from a regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204)... or reading classics such as *Matering Regular Expressions, 3rd Ed* or *The Regular Expressions Cookbook, 2nd Ed* .

For tools, you can use:

- Online: [Regex_for_range](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)
- Offline: the only one I'm aware of is `RegexMagic` (not free) by regex guru Jan Goyvaerts. It's his beginner regex product, and as I recall it has a great range of options for generating numbers in a given range, among other features.
- If the conditions are too complex, auto-generate two ranges... then join them with an alternation operator `|`

**D. An Exercise: Building a Regex for the Specs in the Question**

These specs are quite wide... but not necessarily vague. Let's look at the sample values again:

```
123,456,789
-12,34
1234
-8
```

How do the first two values relate? In the first, the comma matches groups of powers of three. In the second, it probably matches the decimal point in a continental-European-style number format. That does not mean we should allow digits everywhere, as in `1,2,3,44`. By the same token, we shouldn't be restrictive. The regex in the accepted answer, for instance, will not match one of the requirements, `123,456,789` (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR8pO7)).

How do we build our regex to match the specs?

- Let's anchor the expression between `^` and `$` to avoid submatches
- Let's allow an optional minus: `-?`
- Let's match two types of numbers on either side of an alternation `(?:this|that)`:
- On the left, a European-style digit with optional comma for decimal part: `[1-9][0-9]*(?:,[0-9]+)?`
- On the right, a number with thousands separators: `[1-9][0-9]{1,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})+`

The complete regex:

```
^-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:,[0-9]+)?|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})+)$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rN7fX8).

This regex does not allow European-style numbers starting with `0`, such as `0,12`. It's a feature, not a bug. To match those as well, a small tweak will do:

```
^-?(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:,[0-9]+)?|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})+)$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rV2qK5).

Answer (score 4):

```
^[-+]?(\d{1,3})(,?(?1))*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Lyx0F0y1LORvNhwA)

**So what does it?!**

- `^` marks the beginning of the string
- `[-+]?` allows a *minus* or *plus* right after the beginning of the string
- `(\d{1,3})` matches at least one and max three (`{1,3}`) digits (`\d` - commonly `[0-9]`) in a row and groups them (the parenthesises `(...)` builds the group) as the first group
- `(,?(?1))*` ok... let's break this down

  - `(...)` builds another group (*not so important*)
  - `,?` matches a comma (if existent) right after the first sequence of digits
  - `(?1)` matches the pattern of the first group again (remember `(\d{1,3})`); in words: at this point the expression matches a sign (plus/minus/none) followed by a sequence of digits possibly followed by a comma, followed by another sequence of digits again.
  - `(,?(?1))*`, the `*` repeats the second part (comma & sequence) as often as possible
- `$` finally matches the end of the string

the advantage of such expressions is, to avoid to define the same pattern within your expression again and again and again... well, a disadvantage is sometimes the complexity :-/

Comment: This doesn't handle floats -- not with a dot as a decimal anyway.

Comment: that's true, and it was not the goal ... it matches the requested inputs as requested

Comment: It also matches `1,2,3,4,5` which was not requested.  https://regex101.com/r/T3m0iQ/1 Your pattern makes no distinction between commas used as thousands separators and commas used as decimal character.  The validation is not very strong.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^-?[\d\,]+$
```

It will allow an optional `-` as the first character, and then any combination of commas and digits.

Comment: This is a noticeably weak validation as pointed out by Paul in the previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
^-?    # start of line, optional -
(\d+   # any number of digits
|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*))  # or digits followed by , and three digits
((,|\.)\d+)? # optional comma or period decimal point and more digits
$  # end of line
```

Comment: Why not reduce `(,|\.)` to `[,.]`?

Answer (score 0):

In java, You may use `java.util.Scanner` with its `useLocale` method

```
Scanner myScanner =  new Scanner(input).useLocale( myLocale)

isADouble = myScanner.hasNextDouble()
```

Answer (score -3):

For the examples:

```
    ^(-)?([,0-9])+$
```

It should work. Implement it in whichever language you want.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
    boxValue = boxValue.replace(/[^0-9\.\,]/g, "");
```

This RegEx will match only digits, dots, and commas.

Comment: Why would you post this? It offers nothing different to the highly upvoted answers already there.