# Regular expression JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have modal pop up for adding data, I have to validate textbox using JavaScript regular expression for numeric values only. I want to enter only numbers in text box, so tell me what is proper numeric regular expression for that?

Comment: Is is integers only or do you want to have stuff like floats, rationals, scientific notation or complex?

Comment: And, actually, I messed up the pattern. It should be `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` (The final * would allow `1.2.3.4`, which wouldn't be a valid number.)

Comment: Jakob's question is worth repeating: What, exactly, is a "numeric value"? See: [What’s a Number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184)

Comment: Even better just put <input type="number">, but otherwise /^[0-9]$/

Answer (score 2):

Why not using isNaN ? This function tests if its argument is not a number so :

```
if (isNaN(myValue)) {
   alert(myValue + ' is not a number');
} else {
   alert(myValue + ' is a number');
}
```

Comment: isNAN will report a number for '0xabcd' since it is a valid hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as simple as:

```
function hasOnlyNumbers(str) {
 return /^\d+$/.test(str);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wML3a/1/

Answer (score 0):

`^\d+$`
of course if you want to specify that it has to be at least 4 digits long and not more than 20 digits the pattern would then be => `^\d{4,20}$`