# A regular expression that matches 25 chars and starts with digits

Tags: regex, regular-language, maskedtextbox

I have a text field which I need to validate using a regex. My requirement is as follow:

> `CCCCNNNNNN` or `CCCCNNNNNNN` (Template)
>
> `1234ABCDEFG` or `123-ABCDEFG` (Example string)

Rules:

- The whole string is maximum 25 characters
- The first four characters (CCCC) must be alphanumeric
- CCCC is 4 characters exactly and can be digits or number
- CCCC can have a dash sign as 4th character
- NNNNNNNNNNNN can be up to 21 characters and only numbers

E.g. `AAAA` `1234` `A58-` is a valid string for CCCC.

Here is my research notes:

- I will need to match numerics first
- I will need the `+` char to specify to match this pattern X times
- I will need to match letters after that for 8-9 spaces

There is a wonderful post on RegEx patterns here:

[Matching numbers with regular expressions — only digits and commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184)

My goal is to apply this REGEX pattern to a text box Mask in a WinForms app.

Comment: I've deleted my answer - please go back and write a sensible question.

Comment: So sorry, I've clarified my requirements. Hope this provides a clearer idea of what I need.

Comment: not quite enough: to me, "first four characters (CCCC) must be alphanumeric" means either `ABCD` or `1234` and the requirement "NNNNNNNNNNNN can be up to 21 characters and only numbers" conflicts with your example `1234ABCDEFG`. then, what does `I will need to match letters after that for 8-9 spaces` mean, exactly?

Comment: try to state what is allowed - and if necessary, what is not allowed - in a form like the comments in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

....

....

...yeah - I think the answer you are looking for (and I stress "***think***") is this expression:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z]{3}[0-9A-Za-z-]\d{0,21}$
```

thats:

```
^               # assert beginning (not in the middle)
[0-9A-Za-z]{3}  # three characters that are: 0-9 or a-z (upper or lower)
[0-9A-Za-z-]    # one character that is: 0-9 or a-z (upper or lower) or a dash
\d{0,21}        # anywhere from 0 to 21 digits
$               # assert at the end (not somewhere in the middle
```

If you want to match several cases of this expression, put the above expression (minus the assertions) into parantheses (`()`) along with whatever is allowed to separate these values - I chose `\s` or "whitespace") and then use the `+` quantifier:

```
^([0-9A-Za-z]{3}[0-9A-Za-z-]\d{0,21}\s+)+$
```

will match/validate the following input:

```
1234567890 AAAA123456789012345678901 GGG-123       hhh5   A1B2000000000
```

If you wanted something else, you'll have to ask a clearer question (there's a lot of contradiction and repetition in your question that makes it EXTREMELY confusing)

Comment: last I checked, a standard MaskedTextBox does not use regular expressions

Comment: Thank you for taking a shot at answering this despite the contradictions Code Jockey; I've cleaned up my question to provide straight forward requirements for my expression validation rules.

Comment: The control I'm using is a 3rd party control which allows for MaskTypes and RegEx masks

Comment: @Shawn How far off is the expression (at least based upon my rephrasing of the requirements) - what is wrong or needs to be changed/tweaked a little or added or removed?

Comment: Thank you @CodeJockey this seems to be what I needed to get started. Any adjustments to the regex I will research and implement myself. Thanks again; your help is very much appreciated.