# Finding if a string is 'numeric only' using tr1 regex

Tags: c++, regex, string, numeric, tr1

tIs it possible for me to detect if a string is 'all numeric' or not using tr1 regex?
If yes, please help me with a snipped as well since I am new to regex.

Why I am looking towards tr1 regex for something like this, because I don't want to create a separate function for detecting if the string is numeric. I want to do it inline in rest of the client code but do not want it to look ugly as well. I feel maybe tr1 regex might help. Not sure, any advises on this?

Comment: What does "numeric only" mean?  If you mean "all of the characters are digits," why do you think a regular expression would be more effective than `std::find_if_not(begin(s), end(s), (int(*)(int))std::isdigit) == end(s)`

Comment: Is `1e6` numeric? Is `-1` numeric?

Comment: Yes I meant "all of the characters are digits".

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I don't think regex would be better. I just didn't think it through to find an elegant enough solution. Your looks very elegant. Thanks.

Comment: @bits when you say "*numeric only*" do you mean a string containing only digits (0-9) or should it be a valid (decimal) number?

Comment: Please see: [What’s a Number?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184/433790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test whether the string has all numeric characters, you can use `std::find_if_not` and `std::isdigit`:

```
std::find_if_not(s.begin(), s.end(), (int(*)(int))std::isdigit) == s.end()
```

If you do not have a Standard Library implementation with `std::find_if_not`, you can easily write it:

```
template <typename ForwardIt, typename Predicate>
ForwardIt find_if_not(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Predicate pred)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        if (!pred(first))
            return first;

    return first;
}
```

Comment: `std::find_if_not` is not mentioned in [c++ algorithm reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/). I am not sure why? I guess I will have to implement the template as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @bits:  It was added in C++11, and cplusplus.com is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `string::find_first_not_of` member function to test for numeric characters.

```
if (mystring.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "numeric only!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression for this is rather trivial. Just try to match `"\\D"`. This will match on any character that's not a digit. If you'd like it to include a decimal separator too, you could use `"[^\\d\\.]"`, which translates to "not a digit or dot".

However, how about simply using `strtol()` to read the number? You'll be able to retrieve a pointer to the first non-number character. So, if this points to the end of the string, it's been fine. Plus side here is, you won't even need TR1 for this.

Comment: Good point. But easy to do when reversing: The string is valid, if you get a match on `"^-?\\d+$"` or `"^-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$"`