# How to check if an input box contains only numbers or commas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given:

```
 var input_val = $('#field').val();
```

How do I check whether input_val contains only numbers or commas? The solution must work in the 4 main browers.

Comment: There was a similar post to this a couple of years ago.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas

Comment: Do you mean "digits" (e.g. `0`, `1` etc) or "numbers" (e.g. `-3.14`)?

Comment: Perhaps large US numbers like `1,000,000` or numbers with European decimal point: `3,14` - we will not know unless @Hard worker works harder on how he asks questions ;)
And actually it sounds like homework even, so how hard does hard worker works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^(\d|,)+$/.test(input_val)` will return `true` as long as `input_val` only contains digits and/or commas.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function

```
function containsNumbersAndCommasOnly(str) {
     return /^[0-9,]+$/.test(str);
}
```

by calling

```
if (containsNumbersAndCommasOnly(input_val)) {

}
```

Comment: `1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9` will pass this too

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of the response from @Adil and a community post answer from a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric).  The combination of the two works better than either individually but there are still some issues... 12,12,12 would be valid here so would 1,,,,,,,,,9 as pointed out as @mplungjan.

For my purposes this is as far as I am willing to go but someone good with regex might add a solution that detects for single instances of commas followed but not preceded by a minimum of 3 digits.

```
if(!(!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n))){
    return /^(\d|,)+$/.test(n);
}else{
    return true;
}
```