# Improve my regex for numbers in a string

Tags: .net, regex

I have created a bulky .net regex expression that works, but is quite inefficient. I'd have to assume that there is a more condensed way to write it, but I can't seem to find one.
What I need it to do:

- match positive and negative integers
- match positive and negative decimals with or without any numbers preceding the decimal
- work for .NET since it is being used in a WPF application

Examples of matches from arbitrary example strings:

- "7" from "7in"
- "-4" from "-4 mm"
- ".345" from " .345"
- "-.43" from " -.43 cm"
- "0.16" from "$0.16"
- "-10.04" "-10.04"

What I need to avoid:

- matching the second number in a range as a negative
  *ex: matching "-3500" in "1000-3500 RPM" (should match 1000 and 3500)

My regex:

`(?<![0-9])(-)\.\d+|(?<![0-9])(-)\d+\.\d+|(?<![0-9])(-)\d+|\.\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+`

The Breakdown:

`?<![0-9])(-)\.\d+` - 
a negative decimal without numbers before the decimal and then make sure 
there is no number before the dash

OR

`(?<![0-9])(-)\d+\.\d+` - 
a negative decimal with numbers before the decimal and then make sure 
there is no number before the dash

OR

`?<![0-9])(-)\d+` - 
a negative integer without a number preceding the dash

OR

`\.\d+` - 
find a positive decimal with no preceding numbers

OR

`\d+\.\d+` - 
find a positive decimal with preceding numbers

OR

`\d+` -
find an positive integer

Now, from what I understand, this should be able to be combined into fewer "OR" segments. Id guess that you can at least combine the positive and negative cases and probably the optional numbers proceeding a decimal. Any increased performance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4246077/1679863). You don't need anything else.

Comment: Is this a rang `-1--3`? negative 1 to negative 3.  Can ranges have whitespace between the hyphen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `(?<!\d)\s*-?\d*(\.\d+)?`

Uses a negative lookbehind to assert there are no digits before the dash, also only allows only one decimal point (if any).

Answer (score 0):

How about this one: `-?(\d*\.)?\d+` ?

Comment: this will match the case he wants to avoid.

Comment: Close, but it doesn't solve the issue with the range situation. Thanks

Comment: It looks like adding the lookback to the optional dash will do it though ((?<![0-9])-?)(\d*\.)?\d+

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this does the job: `(?<![0-9])-?\.?([0-9]+)?\.?[0-9]+`

Tested [here](http://regexr.com?35qf9)

**edit**- Condensed slightly: `(?<![0-9])-?\.?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`

Tested [here](http://regexr.com?35qfl)

Comment: this would allow the matching of two periods