# RegExp to be recursive

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

I have the following string:

```
string>string25>string89 > anotherString
```

And I have following regExp:

```
^[\w\_\-\.\d]+(?:\s*)?(?:\>)+(?:\s*)[\w\_\-\.\d]*
```

And then I want my regExp to be recursive and starts from the first character to the last character. My language is Javascript, but I want to see if my regExp has this capability? or should I use `while()` condition? I need a solution of regExp itself and if it is not possible, then please give the solution of Javascript `while()` itself.

EDIT: I want to capture this:

```
string>string25
string25>string89
string89 > anotherString
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Side note: `[\w\_\-\.\d]` can (should) be shortened to `[\w.-]`.

Comment: Expected output would be nice, but it does sound like some form of loop would make more sense than recursion.

Comment: There's no need for "recursion". `/[^>]+(?=>)/g` would do the job

Comment: @user3853834 That's not called "recursion". `/(?=([^>]+>[^>]+))[^>]+>/g` would do the job. [See the content of group 1](http://regex101.com/r/eR0nP1/1)

Comment: @HamZa wonderful...post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so much about recursion as getting **all matches**. In Javascript you have to make your regular expression *global*

```
/([^>]+)/g
```

This will match all sub strings in your string:

```
string
string25
string89  (including space at the end)
```

Or you could easily just split your string with `>` delimiter and collect individuals:

```
yourString.split(">");
```

### Edit

After you've written your desired result I'd suggest you go with [@HamZa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865411/regexp-to-be-recursive#comment38616888_24865411) that uses positive lookahead. And you'll get pairs back.

```
/(?=([^>]+>[^>]+))[^>]+>/g
```

#### Some explanation

Regular expressions parse strings from from left to right iterating over each character (to simplify the process). Positive lookaheads on the other hand don't progress the current parsing position but rather do what they say: they lookahead if their expression is found:

`t(?=s)` will match second `t` in `streets` because it sees that `s` is followed by `t`. But parsing after this match will continue from `t` on.

I hope this explains it a bit.

#### Actual solution expression

But to explain the actual regular expression it's a rather clever one how it progresses string parsing:

1. It first has a positive lookahead (it doesn't increment parsing position) to check if at current parsing position there's a pair you're looking for:

   ```
   (?=([^>]+>[^>]+))
   ```
2. If lookahead matches such a pair it stores it as a match (hence the inner parentheses)
3. Then after the lookahead we have the single string expression `[^>]+>` that doesn't get stored as a match (not within parentheses) but rather takes care that parsing progresses for a single string up to and including the next `>` character.
4. Because this regular expression is global it then starts to do a match all over again but this time from the next character position after `>` character as the previous parsing progressed/incremented/advanced to it.

Comment: I love his solution; I appreciate if you explain it so both me and future visitors make use of it.

Comment: @user3853834 I didn't post an answer since it's quite long to explain. But I've answered a similar situation before. Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20939737). If it's still unclear, ping me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex)

Comment: @user3853834: Does the added explanation clear things a bit for you?

Comment: Thanks both of you. The given explanation rather clears things for me. Thanks.