# Regex to match integers, decimals and fractions

Tags: .net, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that can match integers, decimals and fractions from a string:

Here are some examples

```
11.325 x 55.65
11x13
11”x13”
11” x 13”
11 3/8 x 15 7/8 
11 3/8” x 15 7/8“
```

Explanation of above examples:

1. Two decimals
2. Two integers
3. Two integers with quote to represent inches
4. Same as above but with spaces
5. Two integers each followed by a fraction
6. Same as above with a quote after fraction for inches

So far I have come up with code that will match any numeric values, i.e. integers and decimals, but I'm stuck on the fractions.

```
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(curCellVal + "", "[\d.]+")
```

The above code gives me 6 matches for `11 3/8” x 15 7/8“`, I need it to give me 2.

I'm not competent with regex so any help would be much appreciated.

My language of preference is VB.net.

Comment: Are you looking to match each number individually, or the entire string as a single match?

Comment: each number individually.

Comment: I have a vague impression that people won't appreciate your question. There's no effort shown, there are many formats and it's not clear what you want to obtain.

Comment: You might start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184)

Comment: My advice: become competent. The way to solve regexp problems is to very carefully describe the "language" -- the set of strings -- you intend to accept. Instead of writing examples, write English descriptions that use OR a lot.  You want to accept the digit zero,  OR any non-zero digit followed by any number of digits, OR any digit followed by a point followed by one or more digits, OR...  list *all* the cases. Once you have all the cases it is much easier to write a regexp.

Comment: Positive examples + textual description thereof != specification, not even a vague one.

Comment: `[\/\d.]+` would include the front slash in your matches. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: [Here you go](http://regex101.com/r/uZ9pP4) for all the pain you've gone through :)

Comment: @remus Almost, `10 3/8` should be one match, since it's a number and a fraction. only including the slash would make it into 2 matches.

Comment: Do you need to capture the quote characters if they appear or just the numbers?

Comment: @HamZa Thanks so much, but this regex is for php. I'm looking for vb.net

Comment: @p.s.w.g Just the numbers.

Comment: @boruchsiper How about trying to adapt the information you've been given so far to your particular situation. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: @boruchsiper Why don't you test it out ? It should work. I also tested it on [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) but since I need an account there to share a link I've just provided another online tester.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this one a shot:

```
(\d+[\/\d. ]*|\d)
```

http://regex101.com/r/oO9yI9

In the future, I'd suggest making your question more clear so we can actually understand what you're trying to do -- provide inputs, expected outputs, and include the programming language you're using.

vb.net is PCRE compliant, so you should be able to use this:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(\d+[\/\d. ]*|\d)")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("11.325 x 55.65")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    # this matches, so you'll get a value
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression should work:

```
@"\d+(\.\d+|\s+\d+/\d+)?"
```

This matches any sequence of one or more digits, optionally followed by an either a `.` followed by one or more digits *or* a sequence of one or more whitespace characters, followed by one or more digits, followed by a `/`, followed by one or more digits.

For example:

```
Dim inputs = New String() { _
    "11.325 x 55.65", _
    "11x13", _
    "11””x13””", _
    "11”” x 13””", _
    "11 3/8 x 15 7/8 ", _
    "11 3/8”” x 15 7/8““" }
For Each input in inputs
    Console.Write(input + ": ")
    For Each match as Match in Regex.Matches(input, "\d+(\.\d+|\s+\d+/\d+)?")
        Console.Write(" (" + match.Value + ") ")
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Produces the output:

```
11.325 x 55.65:  (11.325)  (55.65) 
11x13:  (11)  (13) 
11"x13":  (11)  (13) 
11" x 13":  (11)  (13) 
11 3/8 x 15 7/8 :  (11 3/8)  (15 7/8) 
11 3/8" x 15 7/8":  (11 3/8)  (15 7/8)
```

Comment: The previous version of your answer worked but now it doesn't. It was similar to the expression in @remus answer. Thanks very much anyway!

Comment: @boruchsiper I don't understand what you mean. The only thing I changed in this answer was how I printed the results.

Comment: I believe this is what you wrote in the previous answer `\d+[\/\d. ]*\d`. Maybe it was someone else?

Comment: @boruchsiper Answers with the same score may be randomly order, so you were probably looking at the other answer. In any case, I'd be happy to correct this answer if you can tell me why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oops my bad, just checked again and it does work. I already awarded the answer to @remus, but I voted you up.

Comment: @boruchsiper No problem, I just wanted to make sure I didn't make a mistake somewhere. Glad I could help.