# Tcl regular expressions

Tags: regex, tcl

```
set d(aa1) 1 
set d(aa2) 1                                                                                                                   
set d(aa3) 1
set d(aa4) 1
set d(aa5) 1
set d(aa6) 1
set d(aa7) 1
set d(aa8) 1
set d(aa9) 1
set d(aa10) 1
set d(aa11) 1
set regexp "a*\[1-9\]"
set res [array names d -glob $regexp]
puts "res = $res"
```

In this case, the result is:

```
res = aa11 aa6 aa2 aa7 aa3 aa8 aa4 aa9 aa5 aa1
```

But when I change the regexp from `a*\[1-9\]` to `a*\[1-10\]`, the result becomes:

```
res = aa11 aa10 aa1
```

Comment: Globs aren't regexps; they're a [more restricted language](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) that is easier to write but not as powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your character class.

- `[1-10]` does not mean a digit from 1 to 10
- It means `1-1`, which is a character ranging from `1` to `1` (i.e., simply a `1`), or a `0`. This explains your output.
- to express a digit from 1 to 10, use this: `(?:10?|[2-9])` (as one of several ways to do it.
- therefore your regex becomes `a*(?:10?|[2-9])`
- note that if your engine does not allow non-capturing group, you need to remove the `?:`, for: `a*(?:10?|[2-9])`

Answer (score 3):

You need to be sure what you're trying to match because `glob` style matching and `regexp` style matching are different in many aspects.

From [the docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34), glob has the following:

- `*` matches any sequence of characters in string, including a null string.
- `?` matches any single character in string.
- `[chars]` matches any character in the set given by chars. If a sequence of the form x-y appears in chars, then any character between x and y, inclusive, will match. When used with `-nocase`, the end points of the range are converted to lower case first. Whereas `{[A-z]}` matches `_` when matching case-sensitively (since `_` falls between the `Z` and `a`), with `-nocase` this is considered like `{[A-Za-z]}` (and probably what was meant in the first place).
- `\x` matches the single character `x`. This provides a way of avoiding the special interpretation of the characters `*?[]\` in pattern.

Since you are using glob style matching, your current expression (`a*\[1-9\]`) matches an `a`, followed by *any* characters and any one of 1 through 9 (meaning it would also match something like `abcjdne1`).

If you want to match at least one `a` followed by numbers from 1 through 10, you will need something like this, using the `-regexp` mode:

```
set regexp {a+(?:[1-9]|10)}
set res [array names d -regexp $regexp]
```

Now, this regexp is I believe the more natural one for a beginner (`(?:[1-9]|10)` meaning either 1 through 9, or 10, but you can use the form that zx81 suggested with `(?:10?|[2-9])` meaning 1, with an optional 0 for 10, or 2 through 9).

`+` means that `a` must appear at least once for the array name to match.

If you now need to match the full names, you will need to use anchors:

```
^a+(?:[1-9]|10)$
```

Note: You cannot use glob matching if you want to match at least one `a` followed by digits, and alternation (the pipe used `|`) and quantifiers (`?` or `+` or `*`) the way they behave in regexp are not supported by glob matching.

One last thing, use braces to avoid escaping your pattern (unless you have a variable or running a function in your pattern and can't do otherwise).

Comment: You might need to anchor those REs; Tcl doesn't ever anchor them by default…