# Perl regular expression to capture contents

Tags: regex, perl

Below is the script i used to capture the secs

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n='Created posting 187294181 (sny/sny_AF8F46748A50416A9F1FF2BD7) in 0.261 secs';
my $m='Created posting 187294183';


if($n=~/Created\s+(resume|posting)\s+(\d+).*?([\d\.]*)/i)
{
   print "$1 $2 $3\n";
}
```

Iam getting $3 as blank.Can anyone help me what mistake i have done in the regex to capture secs.Both the $m and $n should match the regex.

Output:

```
posting 187294181
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
(resume|posting) (\d+)(?:.*?in ([\d.]+) secs)?
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/4), inspect the capture Groups in the right pane.

In your Perl code:

```
if ($subject =~ m/(resume|posting) (\d+)(?:.*?in ([\d.]+) secs)?/i) {
   # We matched!
   print "$1 $2";
   # Is Group 3 set? 
   if (defined $3) { print "$3"; }
   print "\n";
}
```

**Explanation**

- `(resume|posting)` captures `resume` or `posting` to Group 1.
- `(\d+)` captures the digits to Group 2.
- `(?:` opens our optional non-capture group
- `.*?` lazily matches chars up to ....
- the literal `in`, then
- `([\d.]+)`we capture the time to Group 3
- match literal chars `secs`
- `)?` closes the non-capture group and makes it optional

Comment: FYI added [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/4), please have a look at the capture groups in the right pane. :) Will add explanation.

Comment: He might have an issue with $3 sometimes being undefined. `for ($n, $m) { if (/Created \s+ (resume|posting) \s+ (\d+) \b (?: .*? \b in \s+ \b ([\d.]+) \b \s+ secs) ? /x) { printf "1=%s 2=%s 3=%s\n", $1, $2, defined($3) ? $3 : "<undef>" } `.  There are better ways of matching floats, and as written there may be false positives on nefarious naughty data.  But if all data are “guaranteed” good, well, then ok.

Comment: If only people just write in `/x` mode all the time, they would never have to have these extra explanations; that would be in the comments.

Comment: @tchrist Yes I'm aware that the float-matching is quick-and-dirty, that seemed alright with his input. Group 3 is inside an optional non-cap group so he needs to test it in the `if`. But I'm sure you know all that.

Comment: If using v5.10 or higher, of course `$3 // "<undef>"` is also possible, and only evaluates `$3` once.  Which isn’t a big deal, but still.

Comment: @tchrist I'm a big fan of `/x` / `(?x)` / `VERBOSE`, but for some reason on short SO answers they often scare people away. :) I end up creating these explanations by hand as I wasn't happy with automated tools (they divide into tokens, whereas to explain to a human, you need to find the right unit)

Comment: @tchrist Okay, added the whole test so that he prints $1, $2 and optionally $3. :)

Comment: Compiling with `VERBOSE` works in Python, yes. But Java’s implementation is rather nasty: you end up having to put `\n` as a two-character escape in the pattern to stop the `# comment \n`, which rather sucks.

Comment: Sigh. What is this non-inlined "demo" habit that people seem to think is some sort of good idea? Unless you run it through Perl, you will never be sure it works that way, and PCRE != Perl.  However, a link to a video running it under Damian’s `Regex::Debugger` module: that would be really cool.

Comment: @tchrist Here's [a monster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24463086/1078583) I'm working on, wouldn't dream of it without `(?x)`... Completed part B, working on part C. Btw also love `DEFINE` for refactoring, do you use that? @HamZa uses it very efficiently and I've been starting to make manageable monsters with it.

Comment: Yes, I do use `DEFINE`.  [Look at some of my gnarlier regex answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A471272+%5Bregex%5D) It allows you to do top-down programming again, with regex subroutines. It’s a bit slow though in that the optimizer can’t get all clever with it.

Comment: Yes, looking at your answers is on my list!!! I'm retiring from a few weeks of intense answering as of July 1st so will have more time. :) Regarding `DEFINE`, don't think it exists in Barnett Python, I scribbled an idea to replace it the other day but haven't fully tested it: `(?:(Tigers)$^)?match whatever(?1)` So here Group 1 is a definition for `Tigers`

Comment: Right, `DEFINE` is only in Perl and PCRE last I checked, and not yet in Barnett’s great Python `regex` module.  The last few regexes [in the number-matching answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184) use `(?&GROUPNAME)` stuff for easier writing and reading.

Comment: Aha. I'll double check. Here's a demo of my [DIY DEFINE for Python](http://regex101.com/r/rK1rY7/1) (engine is PCRE but would work in `regex` module)