# PHP Get the first numbers on a string before text, ignore everything else

Tags: php

I have a string and I'm trying to get only the numbers, which is currently working.

My problem is that I just want to get the numbers before the word results and ignore everything else.

Here's an example string:

```
echo '381,000,000 results 1. something here 12345566778898776655444';

$theContent = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $theContent);
echo $theContent;
```

How can I just get the numbers before the word results and ignore results and everything after that?

Comment: Given that commas aren't part of a number, but merely a way of formatting a number for display purposes, you'll have to make allowances for that

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: Go through this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/matching-numbers-with-regular-expressions-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184) and just use `preg_match()` with a lookahead `(?=\s+results\b)`

Comment: `$theContent = '381,000,000 results 1. something here 12345566778898776655444';
echo $theContent, PHP_EOL;

$theContent = preg_match('/\d+/', preg_replace('/\,/', '', $theContent), $matches);
echo $matches[0];
`

Answer (score 1):

If you want see this:

> 381

use

> ^(\d*)

But if you want see numbers with ","

> 381,000,000

use

> ^([\d,]*)

Comment: It's working but giving me this error: Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '^' found in ...

Answer (score 1):

I would first match all the numbers at start concatenated by `,` and `explode()` them by `,` afterwards:

```
$string = '381,000,000 results 1. something here 12345566778898776655444';
$pattern = '/((^|,)([\d]+))*/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$numbers = explode(',', $matches[0]);

var_dump($numbers);
```

IMO this is the most stable solution.

About the regex pattern: It matches the sequence *start of the line or a `,` followed by one ore more numeric characters* multiple times. It uses capturing groups `()` to separate the numbers from the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get number from this:

```
$theContent = '381,000,000 results 1. something here 12345566778898776655444';

$array = explode(" ", $theContent);

$wantedArray = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (is_numeric(str_replace(",", "", $item))) {
        $wantedArray[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $theContent, $matches);
print_r( $matches);
```

Comment: This would also match the numbers at the end of the line.