# adding numbers to a preg_match expression

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this already working code

```
preg_match ('/^\p{L}[\p{L} _.-]+$/u', $address);
```

but it only validate characters,
I just want it to accept numbers as well.

Comment: You should describe more precisely what you want (with examples and if needed counter-examples) and add what you have already tried. Take a look here too: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: [What's a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184/508666)

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear but as far as I can understand you need to match numbers as well .

```
^[\d\p{L}][\d\p{L} _.-]+$
```

in PHP

```
preg_match ('/^[\d\p{L}][\d\p{L} _.-]+$/u', $address);
```