# How can I accept math.exp as input and use it for calculation in python?

Tags: python

```
b = float(input('enter b: ') # where I entered math.exp(2) for b
c = b+4
```

Comment: `float` does not evaluate expressions. You might try `eval`, but should be _very_ careful with that. Also, requires `math` to be imported first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/6260170

Comment: eval worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I second @tobias_k. Do make sure you check your input value prior to sending along to `eval`. Also, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```py
import math
b = input("enter b: ")
if not 'math.exp(' in b: # add to this list with what you'd like to allow
    raise ValueError 
b = eval(b) # e.g. math.exp(2) as input
c = b + 4
print(c)
```

Be aware that without checking inputs users could input expressions that you would not like to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Regex may be a good option:

```py
import re
import math

exp_pattern = "math.exp([^\d+$])"
equation = input("Enter an Expression : ")

if re.match(exp_pattern, equation):
    b = math.exp(re.compile(exp_pattern).search(equation).group(1))
    c = b + 4
    print(c)
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid Expression")
```

The regex pattern will only match integers so no unexpected `TypeError`s.

For floats or other patterns this post might be helpful: [Matching numbers with regular expressions — only digits and commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/matching-numbers-with-regular-expressions-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184)