# Regex expression to match a currency with spaces around

Tags: regex

The regex is matching the currency properly, for instance $42,000,000 . However, if I write `aaaa$42,000,000` or `$42,000,000aaa` or `aaa$42,000,000aaaa` it's also matching it which shouldn't be the case, it should match only when there are spaces around.

The regex I have is  `/\$(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|0)?(\,\d{1,2})?/g`

I also tried with `/\b\$(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|0)?(\,\d{1,2})?\b/g`
but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you tag your question with the language of your source code, then you might get a better answer. This is especially true if you haven't yet considered solution A of zx81's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378033/1707353).

Comment: Alternative regex: "(?:^|\\s)(\\$\\d+[,\\d]+\\d)(?:$|\\s)". Use matcher.group(1).

Comment: I don't think this kind of question is a good fit for stackoverflow. Try to break it into pieces and make each piece as generic as possible. So that other users can benefit of the answer if we arrive at one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(?<!\S)\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```
(?<!\S)      assert that what precedes is either whitespace or the start of the input
\$           match $
\d{1,3}      match 1-3 digits
(?:,\d{3})*  match zero or more thousands terms
(?:\.\d+)?   optional decimal component
(?!\S)       assert that what follows is either whitespace or the end of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this regex:

```
^\$\d{1,3}(?:(?:\.|\,)\d{3})*$
```

- `^\$\d{1,3}`: line must start with a dollar sign followed by 1 up to 3 digits
- `(?:(?:\.|\,)\d{3})*$`: line can end with an unlimited (or zero) repetition of 3 digits preceded by a comma or a dot

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BBWlIF/2